node_modules started to be created in each project folder instead of in one directory after CRA
Initially, the project structure corresponded to the concept of a monorepository, where all dependencies (modules, packages) are located in the root folder, in node_modules, and all project sources are in ./services`х:
project

node_modules
packages
services
--- server
--- web-client

That is, based on this concept, if you install the express dependency in the server project, then only information about the dependency will be written in its directory - in package.json, and the dependency itself will be installed in node_modules of the root directory.
However, after creating a web-client project using the CRA (create-react-app) template, npm started installing dependencies in node_modules for each project individually, creating that ill-fated folder for them. As a rule, there are only new dependencies installed after the CRA template, or even a .cache folder.
For example, now only the dotenv dependency is installed in the server directory, and the rest are apparently pulled from the root directory.
And for web-client, react-scripts, typescript and .bin folders are created, although typescript is also installed in the root node_modules, and is used in the server project too.
Root package.json:
{
  "name": "draftvariant1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*",
    "services/*"
  ]
}

./services/web-client/package.json:
{
  "name": "web-client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@packages/shared": "*",
    "@packages/build-config": "*",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
}

./services/server/package.json:
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@packages/shared": "*",
    "@packages/build-config": "*",
    "express": "^4.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
  }
}

Moreover, I use webpack, and a separate directory is allocated for its configuration - ./packages/build-config. There is also its own (common) package.json, with all dependencies for webpack (plugins, loaders), and a node_modules folder is also created in this directory! It is worth considering that the node_modules created in a decentralized manner do not duplicate the dependencies installed in the root node_modules, but still, the fact of decentralized creation of node_modules confuses me.
Any questions, including clarifying ones, ideas, suggestions, please? I also welcome any constructive criticism
Thanks in advance

Using CRA, It will default create and install dependencies in directory , where you run npx create-react-app, you can delete delete node_modules folder, and others things and it will use packages from root node_modules. In monorepo, some you use special packages for spacific project, it dont have sense to use it globaly. Answer is not using CRA, create basic templates for base projects(folder structure, scripts, modified package-json without global dependecies) and then run npm i/ci and start project.
